# error al insertar dato en modal con dos formularios en el

Tags: php, mysql

tengo que hacer un insert en un modal que tiene dos formularios, el segundo es una extension para un combo box del primero, el cual es juegos y el segundo es una extension a la categoria.

Por ejemplo en el primer formulario tengo el id y el nombre del juego y su categoria en un combobox, en caso de que la categoria no exista se hace click en un boton que despliega dos inputs que son el id y la categoria del juego(pelea, accion, guerra, etc.)

Entonces pasa que debo hacer que los datos de categoria se introduzcan con ajax para que cargue automaticamente la informacion directo al combobox(esto lo hago) pero al realizar el insert me dice que debo ingresar el juegoID que es una PFK, lo que no me causa mucho sentido, pero asi es el trabajo que me solicitaron, estoy colgado

tablas

```
Juegos
JuegoId Serial NN (PK)
NombreJuego Character varying(126) NN

CategoriaJuegos
JuegoId Integer NN (PFK)
CategoriaJuegoId Serial NN (PK)
NombreCategoria Character varying(126) NN
```

el error en concreto es:

> ## Se produjo un error en la base de datos
>
> Error Number:
>
> ERROR: el valor null para la columna «JuegoId» viola la
>   restricción not null DETAIL: La fila que falla contiene (null, 1,
>   accion).
>
> INSERT INTO "CategoriaJuego" ("CategoriaJuegoId",
>   "NombreJuego") VALUES ('2', 'accion')
>
> Filename:
>   models/Modelo_categoriajuego.php
>
> Line Number: 82

UPDATE

```
modelo
 public function create($post_array = NULL)
 {
//structura JSON de salida del proceso de INSERT
$status = array("status" => "false");

$res = $this->db->insert('CategoriaJuegos',$post_array);
if (!$res) {

    $msg = $this -> db -> _error_message();
    $num = $this -> db -> _error_number();

    $status = array("status" => "false", "error" => "Error(" . $num . ") " . $msg);

} else {
    $status = array("status" => "true", "error" => "false" );
}

return $status;
 }
```

controlador

```
   $action = $this->input->post('action');
    if ($action == 'create') {


        // rescatando los datos del formulario enviados via POST desde el cliente
        $CategoriaJuegoId  = $this->input->post('CategoriaJuegoId ');
        $NombreCategoria  = $this->input->post('NombreCategoria ');


        //arry asociativo con nombres de las columnas de la fila  a insertar
        $post_array = array(
            'CategoriaJuegoId ' => $CategoriaJuegoId ,
            'NombreCategoria ' => $NombreCategoria ,
        );

        //llamada a metodo que realiza el INSERT en la base de datos.    
        $ret = $this->modelo_categoriajuego->create($post_array);

        echo json_encode($ret);
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código php que estas realizando para tus inserciones y tus consultas por favor.

Comment: Según la descripción que haces de la tabla, el error está en tu consulta: `INSERT INTO "CategoriaJuego" ("CategoriaJuegoId", "NombreJuego") VALUES ('2', 'accion')` si observas, estás pidiendo que se inserten datos en la columna `CategoriaJuegoId`, esa columna es de tipo `serial`, es decir, se autoincrementará por sí sola al insertar un registro y puedes omitirla, en cambio **la columna `JuegoId` no es mencionada en la sentencia de inserción**. La solución sería cambiar tu sentencia por algo como esto: **`INSERT INTO "CategoriaJuego" ("JuegoId", "NombreJuego") VALUES (2,'accion')`**